# Resize a row of images to browser width

Tags: jquery, css

In an MVC app there is a row of images across the top of the page, just under the NavBar

The are generated from a DB based on the provided ID, the resultant HTML like this

```
<div id="imageHeader" class="row" style="padding-top:   30px; padding-left: 30px; ">
<div class="img-shadow" >
<img id="TopImage_1" title="The Park" alt="The park - taken in October" src="http://localhost:50675/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/3/Thumbnail" style="height: 140px"/>
</div>
<div class="img-shadow" >
<img id="TopImage_2" title="Picnic Table" alt="The Picnic Table in the Park - taken October 2010" src="http://localhost:50675/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/4/Thumbnail" style="height: 140px"/>
</div>
<div class="img-shadow" >
<img id="TopImage_3" title="The Park" alt="The Park - taken October" src="http://localhost:50675/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/5/Thumbnail" style="height: 140px"/>
</div>
<div class="img-shadow" >
<img id="TopImage_4" title="Hill Grade" alt="View from Hill Grade" src="http://localhost:50675/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/7/Thumbnail" style="height: 140px"/>
</div>
<div class="img-shadow" >
<img id="TopImage_5" title="Some Place" alt="Some place in the spring" src="http://localhost:50675/Secure/ImageViewer/Index/8/Thumbnail" style="height: 140px"/>
</div>
</div>
```

To size them according to the browser width there is this jQuery

```
 $('img').on('load', function () {
    var divWidth = $(window).width();
    var imagePadding = 175;
    var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
    var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
    var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
    var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
    var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();
    var totalImageWidth = parseInt(imagePadding + imageOneWidth + imageTwoWidth + imageThreeWidth + imageFourWidth + imageFiveWidth);
    var widthDifference = divWidth - totalImageWidth;
    var percentDifference = Math.round(widthDifference / divWidth * 100);

    var imageOneHeight = $('#TopImage_1').height();
    var imageTwoHeight = $('#TopImage_2').height();
    var imageThreeHeight = $('#TopImage_3').height();
    var imageFourHeight = $('#TopImage_4').height();
    var imageFiveHeight = $('#TopImage_5').height();

    $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(imageOneHeight + (imageOneHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(imageTwoHeight + (imageTwoHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(imageThreeHeight + (imageThreeHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(imageFourHeight + (imageFourHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(imageFiveHeight + (imageFiveHeight / 100 * percentDifference)) + "px");
        });
```

and to resize them if the browser width changes, this

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var divWidth = $(window).width();
    var imagePadding = 175;
    var imageOneWidth = $('#TopImage_1').width();
    var imageTwoWidth = $('#TopImage_2').width();
    var imageThreeWidth = $('#TopImage_3').width();
    var imageFourWidth = $('#TopImage_4').width();
    var imageFiveWidth = $('#TopImage_5').width();

    var totalImageWidth = parseInt(imagePadding + imageOneWidth + imageTwoWidth + imageThreeWidth + imageFourWidth + imageFiveWidth);
    var widthDifference = parseInt(divWidth - totalImageWidth);
    var percentDifference = Math.round(parseInt(widthDifference / divWidth * 100));

    var imageOneHeight = $('#TopImage_1').height();
    var imageTwoHeight = $('#TopImage_2').height();
    var imageThreeHeight = $('#TopImage_3').height();
    var imageFourHeight = $('#TopImage_4').height();
    var imageFiveHeight = $('#TopImage_5').height();

    $('#TopImage_1').css('height', Math.round(parseInt(imageOneHeight + (imageOneHeight / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_2').css('height', Math.round(parseInt(imageTwoHeight + (imageTwoHeight / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_3').css('height', Math.round(parseInt(imageThreeHeight + (imageThreeHeight / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_4').css('height', Math.round(parseInt(imageFourHeight + (imageFourHeight / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");
    $('#TopImage_5').css('height', Math.round(parseInt(imageFiveHeight + (imageFiveHeight / 100 * percentDifference))) + "px");

});
```

This works well in IE11

[image: IE 11 - loaded]

[image: IE 11 - reduced]

But with Chrome it's a mess

[image: Chrome - loaded]

[image: Chrome - reduced]

I was under the assumption that by changing the width that the height would scale up as it does in IE11... Clearly not :-(

It could be there is a way easier method using CSS (I have tried this, but can't find a way to maintain the aspect), or the jQuery is incorrect. Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

use media query  to set image width e.g below

```
#TopImage_1 {
    width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #TopImage_1 {
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As far as I can see that just spreads each of the five images in a 'squashed' row underneath each other instead of the same row. Also we have no idea if the images are going to be portrait or landscape, so each image size could be different.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you are using variable for each image where you should use classes if size of all images is same

```
<img id="TopImage_1" class = 'MyImages'></img>
var imagesHeight = $('.MyImages').height();
var imagesWidth = $('.MyImages').width();
```

and for resizing of images row you can do this

```
var totalimages = 5
var Screenwidth = window.screen.availWidth
var ScreenHeight = window.screen.availHeight
var imagesHeight = ScreenHeight / 5
var imagesWidth = ScreenWidth / 5

$('.MyImages').css({'width':imagesWidth , 'height' : imagesHeight})
```

and remember that

```
$(window).width()
```

method does not work anymore , you can also try replacing  it with

```
 var Screenwidth = window.screen.availWidth
```

in your own code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know .width had been dropped - I will try availWidth... Each image can be a different size, or even a portrait/landscape mixture, hence the calculation for each one